# what y parameter means in knn sklearn fit function

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

im new in this field and im trying to use knn alghorithm from sklearn.

i found that i need to train the model with the function fit, where in there i pass first argument X as training set, and second argument y as Target values. i trying to understand what the Target values parameter y means. someone used this knn sklearn algorithm and can explain it to me?

here in the documentation-
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html

i saw that they used also only X as parameter sometimes, but when i try to pass only X  it says that also y is required.

Comment: Y is the label or variable you wanna predict , X are the the features which you will train on in order to do the prediction , i suggest you read about supervised learning before start playing with code

Comment: tnx man you are rigt i already figured that out